# Laravel Carbon::today() method return previous day

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have written a function to filter user and agent booked tickets based on date. This is basically an ticket booking application. In this user and agent can book different tickets, so in admin dashboard I am displaying the count of total number of tickets booked by user by today and vice versa for agents. Thus I do this using Carbon to verify with today date. But I am getting different kind of output !

Controller :

```
$ticketsTodayUsers = Booking::with('users')->where("createdAt", ">=", Carbon::today())->whereHas("users", function($subQuery){ 
    $subQuery->where("usertype", "=", "normal");
    })->get();
```

So in this I have two tables, booking and user table by which I am verifying tickets created today using carbon::today() with usertype as normal or agent.

But when I check today (19-sep-2018), I am getting counting result of yesterday (18-sep-2018 ). I am not getting the count of today, which is zero instead the count comes from yesterday or long back like 14-sep-2018. I don't know where I am doing wrong !

The main condition is that I need to separate user and agent bookings counts for each day , so by using createdAt filed from db and carbon today function I tried to match both. But I am not getting expected answer !

Comment: Several things to check: Your database's timezone, your PHP's timezone, your Laravel app's timezone - all three can be different. Then, remove the `->get()` and do `dd($ticketsTodayUsers->toSql(), $ticketsTodayUsers->getBindings())` to output the query and the parameters passed to it. Figure out why that query isn't outputting what you expect.

Comment: When i gave getBindings() , i got date: 2018-09-19 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00) as result and when i gave tosql *"select * from `bookings` where `createdAt` >= ? and exists (select * from `users` where `bookings`.`userid` = `users`.`userid` and `usertype` = ?)"*

Answer (score 2):

Try to use $tz parameter - TimeZone.

```
Carbon::today('Asia/Calcutta');
```

And try to use `WhereData()`, `WhereDay()`:

```
->whereDay('createdAt', '=', date('d'))
```

or

```
->whereDate('createdAt', Carbon::today())
```

Of course with appropriate timezone

```
Booking::with('users')->whereDate('createdAt', Carbon::today('Asia/Calcutta')->toDateString())->whereHas("users", function($subQuery){
            $subQuery->where("usertype", "=", "normal");
        })->get();
```

Comment: Any idea about India's Time zone ?

Comment: 'Asia/Calcutta',

Comment: Nope still i am getting same problem !

Comment: Updated an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$ticketsTodayUsers = Booking::with('users')
     ->whereDate("createdAt", ">=", Carbon::now()->toDateString())
     ->whereHas("users", function($subQuery){ 
         $subQuery->where("usertype", "=", "normal");
     })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
$ticketsTodayUsers = Booking::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->addHour()])->get();
```